# Why does s[len(s)-1:-1:-1] not work?

Tags: python, string, slice, string-length

In looking at some python strings and functions, I discovered this strange quirk of python:

```
s = "hello"
print s[::-1]
```

which then prints: `olleh`

However, `print s[len(s)-1:-1:-1]` doesn't work. My understanding is that it should iterate from the last element `s[len(s)-1]` to the first element `s[0]`. However, it just prints an empty string `''`, which I believe is because in strings of some given length (say, 5), `s[4] == s[-1]`. But, I don't understand why python decides to use `-1` instead of `4`, which is the actual `len(s)`.

Furthermore, `s[len(s):0:-1] + s[0]` works. Why is `len(s)` a valid index? Does python just convert `len(s)` to 0 arbitrarily?

P.S. This is in Python 2.7.8, I'm not sure if it also works in 3.x.x

EDIT: Confirmed to be the same in Python 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The slice notation is this:

```
s[start:stop:step]
```

specifically, `stop` being up to but not including it. Translate this to what you're asking:

```
s[len(s)-1:-1:-1]
```

This is, based on the length of 5 for `'hello'`

```
s[4:-1:-1]
```

or

```
s[4:4:-1]
```

which is an empty, or zero-length string.

---

I have given a much more in-depth exposition of the slice notation here: [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation/24713353#24713353)

Answer (score 2):

Negative indexes are counted from the end of the sequence, so you're just getting `[-1:-1:-1]`, or equivalently `[4:4:-1]` which is zero-length string.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that indexes start at 0, not 1.

`[len(s)-1]` gets the last letter (`'o'`)

`:-1` is just `'o'` again, because you're getting the last value.

So then you want to go from the last value... to the last value... reversed (`-1`). Of course that will return an empty string.

To answer your second question, that's because no errors are ever raised when using index notation. Try doing `print s[32489375:2784:-123]`

Answer (score 1):

You are mapping backwards using a step of negative one.  The default is:

> from 0 to len(collection) by step

When you use a negative step the indices need to be reversed as well, or else you'll go the long way round.  For example, `from 0 to 5 by -1` goes: `0 + -1 = -1`; `-1 + -1 = -2` ... some time later an integer overflows ...)

In order to avoid this long walk around Python reverses the indices when `step` is negative and treats it as:

> from len(collection) to 0 by step

This means that you need to deal with the `start` and `end` values in this case as negative integers from `len(collection)` - so, if you want to get the entire string in reverse, you are looking for:

```
s[-1:-(len(s) + 1):-1]
```

Or, in simpler terms:

> from {the last item in the collection} to {the first item in the collection} by -1

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7315935/135978) also has a good visual explanation for the indices.